# Binomial and Normal distribution X~N(18,5^2)

Tags: normal-distribution, binomial-distribution

I'm stuck with a problem related to binomial and Normal distribution. 
Suppose the amount of time a laptop battery holds its charge is:

$X \sim N(18,5^2)$

Suppose there are 40 students and there is a power outage for 24 hrs.

What is the most most likely no. Of laptops which keep running. I believe this is:

$Y \sim B(40,p)$

How do I find p?

Comment: Welcome to CV. I edited your question for clarity. I hope it reflects what you want, if not, feel free to edit it further.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Based on $X \sim N(18, 5^2)$ calculated the probability that one computer can run more than 24 hrs. It is $p$.

Step 2: The number of computers running more than 24 hrs follows Binomial distribution $Bin(40,p)$. The  most likely number Of laptops running is the mode of the $Bin(40,p)$. So you can find the answer use formula or using graph.